# Get html-like string representation of element in ckeditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react

In Ckeditor 5, I am unable to find a way to extract the string from element. I want to add a feature when user hit enter in the middle of paragraph:

- split the paragraph
- get the content of last paragraph
- remove the last paragraph from the editor

```
editor.model.change( writer => {
  const paragraph = editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();
  writer.split(paragraph);

  const model = editor.model;
  const doc = model.document;
  const root = doc.getRoot();
  // HTML-like string representation of lastParagraph below?
  const lastParagraph = root.getChild(root.childCount - 1); 
})
```

My editor only allow one paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the data controller has `stringify` method that accept model element and return html-string. https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_controller_datacontroller-DataController.html#function-stringify

```
editor.model.change( writer => {
  const paragraph = editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();
  writer.split(paragraph);

  const model = editor.model;
  const root = model.document.getRoot();
  const lastParagraph = root.getChild(root.childCount - 1);
  const splittedMarkup = `<p>${editor.data.stringify(lastParagraph)}</p>`;

  writer.remove(lastParagraph);
  // dispatch an action 
  addMoreMarkup([position, {
    markup: splittedMarkup
  }]);
})
```